# How can I prevent jobs from running based on the files changed compared with master?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have some gitlab jobs in my pipleline which are slow and I'd like to prevent them from running when the changes will not affect the job's outcome.

This is what I have tried:

```yaml
run_tests:
  stage: checks
  script:
    - cargo test
  except:
    - master
    - tags
  only:
    changes:
      - "**/*.rs"
      - "**/Cargo.toml"
      - "**/Cargo.lock"
```

This *sort of* works. If a merge request has multiple commits, this job will not run on any of the commits after the first one, unless a Rust source file has changed.

But the job will still always run on the first commit of the branch, even if there are no changes to Rust source files between this branch and master. Even worse, if the tests fail on the first commit, subsequent commits might skip the tests so broken code could get merged.

How can I change this filter so that the diff is done against the target branch of the merge request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hidden quite deep in the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#using-onlychanges-without-pipelines-for-merge-requests) for `only: changes`, there is this snippet:

> Without pipelines for merge requests, pipelines run on branches or tags that don’t have an explicit association with a merge request. In
> this case, a previous SHA is used to calculate the diff, which
> equivalent to git diff HEAD~. This could result in some unexpected
> behavior, including:
>
> - When pushing a new branch or a new tag to GitLab, the policy always evaluates to true.
> - When pushing a new commit, the changed files are calculated using the previous commit as the base SHA

Which is the scenario you are currently experiencing, where the job always runs on the first commit of the new branch.

---

For this to work as you want, I believe you need to add `only: merge_requests`, however this would require changing your entire pipeline workflow to integrate `only: merge_requests` to your pipeline.

From the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#using-onlychanges-with-pipelines-for-merge-requests):

> With pipelines for merge requests, it’s possible to define a job to be
> created based on files modified in a merge request.
>
> In order to deduce the correct base SHA of the source branch, we
> recommend combining this keyword with only: [merge_requests]. This
> way, file differences are correctly calculated from any further
> commits, thus all changes in the merge requests are properly tested in
> pipelines.

---

Various issues from GitLab:

- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/11427
- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/27875